# How to know when all the messages have been consumed from the queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

I have a Producer which send data to a queue a.
I have a Consumer/engine listening on messages in a.

I am able to process the messages by putting them in a list within my object.

I am now trying to send them to another queue called b.

My problem is:

- How my Consumer/engine can send back the data only after it process all the queue a?

producer.py

```
def on_new_message(self, body):
    # decode the body
    body = self.decode_message(body)
    self.a_list.append(body)

def some_processing(self):
    #do some operations on self.a_list
    ...

def send_message(self):
    #encode the boby
    body = json.dumps(self.some_processing(), ensure_ascii=False),
    #send the message to queu b
    ...
```

Comment: This is not possible without adding some information on the messages. Maybe add a header to the messages that indicates if there are more to come or if a message is the last message that can be expected. But why do you want to do this? What would be the problem if the consumer published a response after every consumed message?

Comment: Because A could contain several messages which need to be processed together. But in some cases A could be a one shot.

Comment: Then mark these messages as belonging together. The consumer will have to keep state about which messages he alread processed and which he still expects to see.

Comment: You can add a header which denotes the start and end of a group message which you want to bundle together. On the consumer side, you can group them up using these header values.